# Stay logged in to a website loaded into a UIWebView

Tags: android, swift, authentication, webview, uiwebview

I am building an app in iOS(swift) and Android, that loads a website in to a webview. The website requires a login and does not persist between uses. Is there a way to pass saved(locally) username and password to the site to be used to login

iOS

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {



    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()




        webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://greatanglers.com")!))

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Android

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();



    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(webView);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.loadUrl("https://greatanglers.com");


private class webViewClient extends WebViewClient {


    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url)
    {
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);
    }



}
```

There isn't a lot of code to it just a simple load the webpage

Comment: Yes, try to be more specific

Comment: Stefan thanks for the speedy reply, What specific information would you need from me. There's not a lot in the the way of code in either project. I'm mostly looking for a direction to take this.

Comment: The website does persist in browser just not in the app

Comment: What kind of web view are you using? What is the class name?

Comment: @DaveWeston I added the code I'm using